# Cosmosdb query is not working on Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I have a cosmos db database with a `simulations` collection and If i make this query on the portal i got some results:

[image: query1]

But in my logic app I got `[]` documents, the same query and the same collection:

[image]

But returns nothing. Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It should work as expected, just created your scenario and it works fine on my side. Make sure your connection databaseId is correct.

[image]

Comment: that's really strange! because when I made the connection on the "Query Documents" action it shows me a dropdown with the database name and after that a dropdown with the collections inside this database (so, if it could load it to the dropdown it means that the connection worked), but even like that the query returns an empty list. The same query that I tested on the cosmosdb data explorer. a

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve this issue @gog?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Exactly same SQL returns no result in Logic Apps but successfully reported on Data Explorer. And the SQL execution is way shorter in Logic Apps, must be something wrong.

Comment: I tested the whole day and can conclude that this activity REQUIRES partition key value as mandatory input otherwise always return null. This is not what I wanted and I think it's not consistent to document

Answer (score 0):

Is your Cosmos DB located in the same region as the Logic App? I'm experiencing the same problem and I think this might cause it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31983051)